# How Do I implement Get Satisfaction on Adobe Business Catalyst?

Tags: java, adobe, business-catalyst, get-satisfaction

I want to use single sign on (aka FastPass) for a Get Satisfaction forum on a site that is hosted in Business Catalyst.  There is documentation for php, RUBY, JAVA, and Python on the Get Satisfaction developers section but Business Catalyst does not "support" server side code.

Any ideas on best practices?

Alex

Answer (score 2):

If it can't be done with JavaScript it can't be done on BC.